# Retrieve the name of an aliased field in Serde

Tags: rust, yaml

I've got a yaml that could have various keys which all are a type of condition.

```
checks:
  should_equal_to: 0
  # or should_greater_than
  # or should_less_than
  # etc etc
```

I know that I can easily load these with serde using alias:

```
pub struct Check {
    pub name: String,
    pub sql: String,
    pub abort_on_fail: Option<bool>,
    #[serde(alias = "should_equal_to")]
    #[serde(alias = "should_greater_than_or_equal_to")]
    #[serde(alias = "should_less_than_or_equal_to")]
    #[serde(alias = "should_greater_than")]
    #[serde(alias = "should_less_than")]
    #[serde(alias = "count_greater_than")]
    #[serde(alias = "percent_min_threshold")]
    #[serde(alias = "percent_max_threshold")]
    #[serde(alias = "should_be_within_10")]
    pub condition: Option<i32>,
}
```

This is fine, but I would like to actually take action when the condition is of a certain type. I figured an enum may work for this, but not exactly sure how to get Serde to tell me what the original alias was.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a `flatten`ed enum instead fo the aliases:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Check {
    pub abort_on_fail: Option<bool>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    pub condition: Option<Condition>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(rename_all="snake_case")]
pub enum Condition {
    ShouldEqualTo(i32),
    ShouldGreaterThan(i32),
    // etc
}
```

Comment: An `Option<Condition>` is already "flat" as it's just one value. `flatten` only works with structs and maps.

Comment: @LucasS. go try it out, `flatten` here flattenes the enum tags. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b5ced3f356440dd7ab976777a892904)

Comment: Oh, right. The `condition` fields is why it expects a map that it can flatten.